# PayPal - Spring - Invalid HTTP method: PATCH

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

When I try to update the state of a Billing Plan using the PayPal REST API on a Spring MVC based application, I encounter a ProtocolException. My stacktrace is as below:

> Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH
>   at java.net.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:428)
>   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.setRequestMethod(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:374)
>   at com.paypal.core.DefaultHttpConnection.createAndconfigureHttpConnection(DefaultHttpConnection.java:83)
>       at com.paypal.core.rest.PayPalResource.execute(PayPalResource.java:364)

How do I work around this problem?

Edit:

Here is my controller code:

```
Plan createdPlan = plan.create(accessToken);  //Create a Billing Plan
createdPlan.setState("ACTIVE");  //Change state of created plan to 'ACTIVE'
createdPlan.update(accessToken);  //Call update method of com.paypal.api.payments.Plan class
```

[Plan.java](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/blob/master/rest-api-sdk/src/main/java/com/paypal/api/payments/Plan.java)

PayPal REST API allows only PATCH requests for updating a Billing Plan as documented [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-plan/#activate-the-billing-plan)

Comment: HTTP methods are `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `TRACE`, `DELETE`. `PATCH`is **not** an HTTP method.

Comment: Can you post you code here,that you are using to communicate with Paypal?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi RFC 5789 would say otherwise: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is going to depend upon whether you're using the Classic SDK or the REST SDK.

In either case, if you look at the source of the Paypal Core SDK [here](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-java), it seems that this issue has already been reported and fixed. In particular in the code of `com.paypal.core.DefaultHttpConnection`  (which is the class in the Paypal SDK setting the PATCH HTTP method) you'll now see the following comment:

```
* Workaround for a bug in {@code HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(String)}
 * The implementation of Sun/Oracle is throwing a {@code ProtocolException}
 * when the method is other than the HTTP/1.1 default methods. So to use {@code PATCH}
 * and others, we must apply this workaround.
 *
 * See issue http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-639
 */
```

So I would expect the latest release to have fixed this issue.

So if you're using the Classic SDK, simply use version 1.6.4 as that is the latest and contains the fix (as seen [here](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-java/blob/v1.6.4/src/main/java/com/paypal/core/DefaultHttpConnection.java)).

For the REST API version of the SDK, the latest version appears to be 0.11.2 which has a dependency on the "latest" version of the CORE SDK, which again I would assume would fix your issue.

Comment: I was using the REST API version of the SDK and updating the version appears to have resolved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting this exact issue using the REST API version 1.13. Anybody else?